# Change only the site url in image source url

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I change the site url in an image source url to a new site url, something like this:

> Original Image: http://domain.com/theme/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/image.jpg
>
> After Replace: http://new-domain.com/new-theme/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/image.jpg

How can I do this using PHP?

Comment: http://php.net/str_replace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I make it by using str_replace
http://php.net/str_replace

```
$old_src = 'http://domain.com/theme/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/image.jpg';
$old_url = 'http://domain.com/theme/';
$new_url = 'http://new-domain.com/new-theme/';

$new_src = str_replace($old_url, $new_url, $old_src ).'<br/>';
echo $new_src;
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to make this change is at a database level.

I do this kind of thing all the time when I deploy a site and I need to change the staging domain (staging.test.com) to the live domain (test.com). Generally, Wordpress generally uses the WP_SITEURL set in wp-config.php to determine asset paths but this is not the case for images.

I use the [Search and Replace for Wordpress databases](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) script and it's pretty solid, just replace:

```
 http://domain.com/theme/
```

with

```
 http://new-domain.com/new-theme/
```

and you should be good to go...

Alternatively, if you're not moving a site then you can change specific instances in the database - for this I'd recommend using a tool like Navicat (for OSX) as this can perform search/replace operations on specific tables.

Comment: But I want to make this action during theme setup, i don't need to make it by this way.
I need something like (explode,  preg_match,  str_replace)